# Table that floats TDs after 4 in a row

Tags: html, css

I want to have a table that will have 4 TDs in each row, and then automatically wrap to a new row. In the html i want to just list the TDs because I will be adding more cells constantly and need them to be in alphabetical order **but don't want to keep shifting the  every time a new one is added**. Each will contain an image and text (could be several words).

I don't understand whether I would use Float or Counter or something else to make them wrap to be 4 cells wide. The last row, if not completely full, doesn't need to be centered. A Border is not necessary either.

this is what it should look like (but with the last row's cell having a nice blank cell)
[image]

Comment: Show us your approche first.

Comment: First of all you would make the table into a list (`ul`/`ol`), because it doesn’t seem to actually contain tabular data. And then simply floating or `display:inline-block` for the `li` will do. You can also look into flexbox, if you want something more advanced that offers some more layout features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a table.

Since you have a list (you explicitly called it that), use a list.

```
<ul class="tiles">
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then apply magic CSS:

```
.tiles {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.tiles>li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Can a list have images and text that are hyperlinked?

Comment: Absolutely they can, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it ;)